# How to fetch entities based on order of insertion via NSOrderedSet relationship?

Tags: swift, sorting, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two entities:

1. Entity A
2. Entity B

Entity A has an ordered to-many relationship to Entity B.
Entity B has an ordered to-many relationship to Entity A.

Entities A and B are unique (no duplicates) and a single Entity B can be added to various Entity A via relationship.

How can I fetch Entities B based on the order of insertion on Entity A via relationship using `NSFetchedResultsController`? I can't use `createdAt` property as it wouldn't work and I can't add a `sortOrder` property because the order will be different on various Entity A.

To make it more clearer with code example.

```
let entityA1 = EntityA(context: context)
let entityA2 = EntityA(context: context)
        
let entityB1 = EntityB(context: context)
let entityB2 = EntityB(context: context)
let entityB3 = EntityB(context: context)
        
entityA1.relationshipToEntityB = NSOrderedSet(array: [entityB1, entityB2, entityB3])
entityA2.relationshipToEntityB = NSOrderedSet(array: [entityB2, entityB1, entityB3])
```

Note the order of the array, it is different for each Entity A. I want `NSFetchedResultsController` to display the order of the array. This is why a dedicated property on Entity B can't work otherwise I would have to make a property for each Entity A which doesn't scale well.

I tried doing this based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51078840/10711707).

```
NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(EntityB.relationshipToA), ascending: true)
```

But it crashed for me as I use `NSTableViewDiffableDataSource`. It make sense to me because which Entity A will it base its sort order on? I also noticed the answer is based on to-one and to-many rather than to-many and to-many which is what I want.

> Fatal: supplied identifiers are not unique.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to accomplish here or rather how this should be accomplished, if you fetch all B and they have a many-to-many relationship to A then how could you possibly sort that based on the relationship order? If b1 is 1st on a1 and second on a2 and b2 is first on a2 and second on a1 then what is the expected result, b1 or b2 first?

Comment: I've updated my question to make it more clearer. To answer your question, the expected result depends on entity A. If you fetch Entities B based on A1, then the order is B1, B2 otherwise B2, B1 for Entity A2.

Comment: Another way to think of it is like Folders and items. Each folder has different items order. Items can be in multiple folders. No duplicates and the order can be user preferred manual ordering rather than sort only by last edit date, created date etc.

Comment: If you only look at one A at a time then it can be seen as a one-to-many relationship and existing solutions should work?

Comment: The first part of your answer, yes and the second part, which solution? The one I tried doesn't work unless I have missed something?

Comment: Sorry I thought you knew how to solve it if it was a one-to-many relationship but I must have misunderstood then.